# UIWebView HTML content indent with image background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIWebView` in my App. I set background image and assign `HTML` as content. This text is  send to me already prepared and I just assign it as view content. The whole view represents a virtual ticket. The HTML content is text of the ticket and background image represents a paper with vertical line of text on the left.

My problem is that the text is very wide and covers vertical line of text. I need to set indent to the web view content on the left to avoid this overlapping.

My first choice was to set `UIImageView` behind web view and to set it as background. But in that case when scrolling the background will be static.

I found examples on the Internet how to use `CSS`, but my `HTML` is predefined and I don't want to complicate App logic with string operations.

Is there a way to make such indent of the `HTML` only of my web view?

**MY CODE**

```
    [self.wwTicket loadHTMLString:singApp.operationTicketData baseURL:nil];

    [self.wwTicket setOpaque:NO];
    [self.wwTicket setBackgroundColor:
     [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ticket.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I receive `HTML` code as `table element` (`tag`) I add text in front and at the back so the whole `HTML` will look as `HTML page`. I set inside the `CSS` using `padding-left`. I set background image to the `UIWebView`. It works.

**REMARK:** 
Padding and body width must be taken into account in order to avoid horizontal scroll. I am not sure if I can disable it with a property from UIScrollView (which is beneath UIWebView).

Answer (score 0):

This will put a 50pt padding on the left side of your HTML content:

```
[webview.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: Sorry @Ian MacDonald, but this is not working I receive fixed image (when scrolling). Inside it I receive also the same image but not fixed. Its content still overlap left image text. And the text of the image is doubled.